# Verb Tense Consistency

Tags: verbs, tenses

Are the verb tenses below correct? The first independent clause is a fact, therefore, it should be in the present. Am I correct?

Our goal ***is*** 100%, and we ***achieved*** a score of 90% last quarter.

Comment: If we can't express facts in the past tense, how can we write history? If your goal endures (say, for the rest of the year), the present tense is fine, and you'll just have to try harder next quarter. If your goal has expired, then use the past tense. Too bad, you failed by 10%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tenses are correct, but there is missing information. Was your goal a score of 100% last quarter, too? It's not clear.

Try, "We aimed for a score of 100%, and achieved 90%, last quarter."

Answer (score 0):

I parse that as "The goal was, *and continues to be*, 100%. We achieved a score of 90% last quarter."

Answer (score 0):

"Our goal is 100%, and we achieved a score of 90% last quarter." is grammatically correct.

Depending on what you want to say, there might be a better way to say it.

If you want to focus on what the current goal is, and compare that to what was achieved last quarter, then your construction is probably the best construction.

If you want to focus on what the goal was, and compare that to what was achieved last quarter, then it would be better to say "Our goal was 100%, and we achieved ..."